# Random Linux freeze (Slackware, mageia, and others)

Tags: linux, laptop, freeze

The last weeks I have been trying to reinstall a Linux distro in my laptop Asus X553S these are the specs:

1. 8 GB Ram
2. Pentium Processor N3700 4 cores, 1.6 GHz
3. Hard drive 20 GB for root partition, 100 GB home partition, 2 GB Swap
4. Integrated intel graphics card

I tried to use other distros as Mageia and Zenwalk (slackware derivated), in both cases occurs a "random freeze" it is a complete freeze, no mouse, no keyboard, no audio/screen events, it is required a hard reset with power button, no one special task before the freeze (looking files, using web browser, etc.), usually takes a few minutes (around 10 or 15 minutes), but in other scenarios occurs very quickly (2 or 3 minutes of usage), the RAM is not an issue their usage rarely is around 1 GB.

I discard a hardware issue because Windows 10 runs fine (slow but fine), I executed Memtest without issues, and actually around two years ago had an Antergos running fine (unfortunately during one update I left it unplugged, the energy drain out, and the SO was useless)

In the log files (messages, syslog, dbus and Xorg), nothing strange appears, and actually the first time that I tried to install and use Linux in that laptop, I had the same troubles (even with Ubuntu family distros, only with Antergos I could avoid the issue).

Any idea or suggestion in order to still investigating? (I would like to know the root cause before to go to the Arch family again).

Comment: How exactly does it freeze? Can you move the mouse pointer? Is the PC pingable? How much RAM do you have? Do you run memory intensive apps like a web browser with many tabs? Please edit your question and add this info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same CPU model and the same issue. Those low-end Intel CPUs have some issues with their power states on Linux.

Try adding kernel parameter `intel_idle.max_cstate=1` in your `/etc/default/grub`:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash intel_idle.max_cstate=1"
```

(The line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` is already there.)

After saving, run `sudo update-grub`. Then restart your machine and test it.

Background info:

- https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=109051
- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelBootParameters